# How I can customize the date format on echarts4r?

Tags: r, echarts, echarts4r

Hi and thanks for reading me
I am trying to make a time series chart with Echarts4r but I would like to change the customization of the axis with the dates. My current code is as follows:

```
library(echarts4r)
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(
  date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2019-01-01"), to = as.Date("2021-05-01"),
                  by = "month"),
  val = rnorm(29, mean = 100, sd = 50)
)
df |> 
  e_charts(date) |> 
  e_line(val)
```

Currently the graph looks like this:

[image]

But I would like it to look like this:

[image]

Over the years located in another row. So far I have not found a way to do it, does anyone know if it is possible somehow?

Again, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a "hack" that makes it work:

First you create a formatter in JS

```
yearMonthDate <- htmlwidgets::JS('function (value) {
  var monthShortNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oc", "Nov", "Dec"
  ];
  
  var d = new Date(value);
  var datestring =  monthShortNames[d.getMonth()] + "  "
  if (d.getMonth()===0) {
    var datestring =  d.getFullYear() + "  " + monthShortNames[d.getMonth()]  + "  "
    
  }
  
  
  return datestring
}')
```

Then you just need to incorporate like such

```
 data %>%
        e_charts(date) %>%
        e_bar(count) %>%
        e_x_axis(
          date, 
          axisPointer = list(show = TRUE),
          axisLabel = list(
            rotate = 45,
            formatter = yearMonthDate
          ))
```

And you get something like that:

[image]

Of course you can change it to look more like your example and add break lines and such.